# Android Custom Spinner issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner

I searched long time before posting the question....

I'm using the following Android version:

- compilesdkversion: 21
- minSdkVersione: 16
- targetSdkVersion: 21

I'm having some problems in customizing my Spinner drop down layout

I call a REST service on the server and it returns to me a List of this object:

**My Spinner model class**

```
public class TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5833474803233889506L;
    private String codiceAllarme;
    private String descrizioneAllarme;

    public TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa(String codiceAllarme, String descrizioneAllarme) {
        this.codiceAllarme = codiceAllarme;
        this.descrizioneAllarme = descrizioneAllarme;
    }

    public TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa() {
    }

    public String getCodiceAllarme() {
        return codiceAllarme;
    }

    public void setCodiceAllarme(String codiceAllarme) {
        this.codiceAllarme = codiceAllarme;
    }

    public String getDescrizioneAllarme() {
        return descrizioneAllarme;
    }

    public void setDescrizioneAllarme(String descrizioneAllarme) {
        this.descrizioneAllarme = descrizioneAllarme;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return descrizioneAllarme;
    }
}
```

I created my own custom adapter:

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class TipoAllarmeSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa> {
    private final List<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa> tipiAllarmi;
    private final Context ctx;
    public TipoAllarmeSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa> tipiAllarmi) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.tipiAllarmi = tipiAllarmi;
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Restituiamo la view normale
        return super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TextView label = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tipo_allarme_spinner_layout, parent, false);
        TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa tamp = tipiAllarmi.get(position);
        if( tamp != null )
        {
            label.setText(tamp.getDescrizioneAllarme());
        }
        else
        {
            label.setText(ctx.getString(R.string.selezione_tipo_allarme));
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

I defined my fragment view:

**Fragment view ricerca_allarmi_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ricercaAllarmiTabViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/ricerca_tipo_allarmi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tipo_allarme_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ricercaAllarmiTabViewId"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ricercaAllarmiTabViewId" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I defined my spinner row view

**Spinner custom row view tipo_allarme_spinner_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_descrizione_tipo_allarme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Elenco notifiche"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my fragment i do the following:

```
public class RicercaAllarmiTab extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG_LOG = RicercaAllarmiTab.class.getSimpleName();
    Spinner tipoAllarmiSpinner;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ricerca_allarmi_tab, container, false);
        tipoAllarmiSpinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.tipo_allarme_spinner);
        populateSpinner();
        return v;
    }

    private void populateSpinner()
    {
        final Context ctx = this.getActivity();
        final Spinner tipoAllSpin = this.tipoAllarmiSpinner;
        MerciPericoloseRestClient.getTipiAllarme(MerciPericoloseRestClient.getTipoMerceAbsoluteUrl(), null, new TipiAllarmiHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String rawJsonResponse, TipoAllarmeMerceAjaxResponse response) {
                try {
                    List<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa> tipiAllarmiJson = response.getPayload();
                    int dimensione = tipiAllarmiJson != null ? tipiAllarmiJson.size()+1:1;
                    final List<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa> tipiAllarmi = new ArrayList<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa>(dimensione);
                    tipiAllarmi.add(new TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa(IConstants.NO_SPINNER_SELECTION, ctx.getString(R.string.selezione_tipo_allarme)));
                    tipiAllarmi.addAll(tipiAllarmiJson);
                    //ArrayAdapter<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, tipiAllarmi);

                    TipoAllarmeSpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new TipoAllarmeSpinnerAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tipiAllarmi);
                    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.tipo_allarme_spinner_layout);
                    tipoAllSpin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                    tipoAllSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa tipo = tipiAllarmi.get(position);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                            Log.i(TAG_LOG, "Nulla scelto");
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG_LOG, "Errore nella costruzione dello spinner "+e.getMessage(), e);
                    (new AlertDialogBuilder(ctx)).buildDialog(ctx.getString(R.string.elenco_tipi_allarmi_dialog_title), getString(R.string.elenco_tipi_allarmi_dialog_message));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, String rawJsonData, TipoAllarmeMerceAjaxResponse errorResponse) {
                Log.e(TAG_LOG, "Errore nel caricamento dei tipi allarmi; " + throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                (new AlertDialogBuilder(ctx)).buildDialog(ctx.getString(R.string.elenco_tipi_allarmi_dialog_title), getString(R.string.elenco_tipi_allarmi_dialog_message));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The ajax call is OK; in fact if I use the StringAdapter (the commented line in populateSpinner method, I'm able in showing the description of my element in spinner (since I overrided the toString method of class TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa)

If I use my custom appender as showed in the code above (the un-commented appender) the spinner is never populated; I get no exception.... simply my spinner is never populated

I really can't understand why it happens... may anybody tell me what I'm missing?

thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after two days I discovered that the problem is in using RelativeLayout inside the custom spinner xml.

if you did the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_descrizione_tipo_allarme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Elenco notifiche"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

it will works fine